# How to optimize the apply call on groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe on which I want to apply below logic to get first row of group having analysis of the individual group.

```
def mark_wakeup_source(df):
    min_id = df['Astart'].idxmin()
    df.loc[min_id, ["Reason", "Count", "CSwitch", "Used"]] = [df.loc[min_id, "type"],
                                                             len(df.index),
                                                             len(df[df['type'] == "Process"]),
                                                             df["Aduration"].sum()]
    return df
```

Here is how I am calling the apply function and combining it.

```
df_t1 = df_t[df_t['type'] != 'Unknown'].copy()
df_t1['Reason'] = "None"
grouped = df_t1.groupby(["CPU", "index"])
df_t1 = grouped.apply(mark_wakeup_source)
df_t = df_t1.append(df_t[df_t['type'] == 'Unknown'])
```

There are 29K+ unique group in my current data and it is taking about ~140 sec to process. I have data which is much larger than this one, I need to optimize it, and running out of clue how to do it.

My data looks like this, before grouping it:

```
    CPU   State     Start      Stop pre_state next_state  index    Astart  \
0     4  Active  0.015417  0.056283        C1         C1      1  0.015429
1     4  Active  0.015417  0.056283        C1         C1      1  0.015437
18    5  Active  0.015492  0.015499        C1         C1      2  0.015495
14    4  Active  0.015417  0.056283        C1         C1      1  0.019524
20    1  Active  0.019921  0.020071        C3         C3      1  0.019938

   Astop          Name     type  Count  CSwitch  Used  Reason  Aduration
0   0.015437        System  Process      0        0     0     None   0.000008
1   0.032188       wpr.exe  Process      0        0     0     None   0.016751
18  0.015498        System  Process      0        0     0     None   0.000003
14  0.019727  ntoskrnl.exe      DPC      0        0     0     None   0.000203
20  0.020064        System  Process      0        0     0     None   0.000126
```

I have reduced the number of groups as much as possible.
Tried Numba but that didn't help at all.
Based on many other answers I tried below code, by returning 0 instead of df, which is taking ~180s:

```
def mark_wakeup_source(df, df_parent):
    df_len = len(df.index)
    min_id = df['Astart'].idxmin()
    df_parent.loc[min_id, ["Reason", "Count", "CSwitch", "Used"]] = 
                                                                 [df.loc[min_id, "type"],
                                                                 df_len,
                                                                 len(df[df['type'] == "Process"]),
                                                                 df["Aduration"].sum()]
    return 0
```

Running out of clues, so looking for some suggestions to do it in optimum way.

Comment: Doesn't really seem like you need an apply here... maybe an `agg` instead.

Comment: My logic is to get row of minimum Astart, in the df and mark it's type as reason. Can this be done using agg? Can you give some example how to do it?

Comment: See answer below, and please consider marking it accepted if it was useful to you, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with a dictionary of aggregation functions.

```
f = {
       'Astart' : [('Reason', 'idxmin')], 
       'type' : [
                  ('Count', 'size'), 
                  ('CSwitch', lambda x: x.eq('Process').sum())
        ], 
       'Aduration' : [('Used', 'sum')]
}
```

Next, `query` + `groupby` and pass `f` to `agg`.

```
v = df.query("type != 'Unknown'").groupby(['CPU', 'index']).agg(f)
v.columns = v.columns.droplevel(0)

v['Reason'] = df.loc[v['Reason'].values, 'type'].values
```

```
v

           Reason  Count  CSwitch      Used
CPU index                                  
1   1          20      1        1  0.000126
4   1           0      3        2  0.016962
5   2          18      1        1  0.000003
```

Note that using `agg` here to aggregate data is a *lot* faster, because it *vectorizes* your operations (which is faster than a loop-like `apply` solution).

Answer (score 1):

To optimize the code, based on @COLDSPEED's suggestion I used:

```
df_min = grouped.agg({'Aduration': 'sum', 'type': 'count', 'Astart': 'min'}).reset_index()
df_min.rename(columns={'Aduration': "Used", 'type': 'Count', 'Astart': 'min'}, inplace=True)
df_with_proc = df_t1[df_t1['type'] == "Process"].groupby(["CPU", "index"]).agg({'type': 'count'}).reset_index()
df_with_proc.rename(columns={'type': 'CSwitch'}, inplace=True)
df_t1 = pd.merge(df_with_proc, df_t1, how="right", on=['CPU', 'index'])
df_t1 = pd.merge(df_min, df_t1, how="right", on=['CPU', 'index'])
```

This can compute in 0.2 sec on same dataframe.